# 多次元配列テーブルデータを Python の reduce() を使って変換する方法について

Tags: python

自分はよく PHP で以下のようにしてデータベースから取得したレコードの変換を行います。

```php
<?php

$list = array(
    array("GROUP" => "A", "NAME" => "りんご", "COUNT" => 1),
    array("GROUP" => "A", "NAME" => "ゴリラ", "COUNT" => 2),
    array("GROUP" => "B", "NAME" => "ラッパ", "COUNT" => 3),
);

$convert_list = array_reduce($list, function($result, $row) {
  if (!key_exists($row["GROUP"], $result)) {
    $result[$row["GROUP"]] = array();
  }

  $result[$row["GROUP"]][] = $row;
  return $result;
}, array());

var_dump($convert_list);
```

結果は以下のようになります。

```php
array(2) {
  ["A"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["GROUP"]=>
      string(1) "A"
      ["NAME"]=>
      string(9) "りんご"
      ["COUNT"]=>
      int(1)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["GROUP"]=>
      string(1) "A"
      ["NAME"]=>
      string(9) "ゴリラ"
      ["COUNT"]=>
      int(2)
    }
  }
  ["B"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["GROUP"]=>
      string(1) "B"
      ["NAME"]=>
      string(9) "ラッパ"
      ["COUNT"]=>
      int(3)
    }
  }
}
```

これと同様の変換をを Python の `reduce()`（ないし別の方法）で行うことはできませんでしょうか。

Comment: PHPに関する質問ではなく、また`php`タグを購読している人が答えたい・知りたいという質問でもないだろう、ということから`php`タグを外しました。

Answer (score 2):

reduceを使う方法もご紹介します。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    from functools import reduce
from pprint import pprint as pp

lst = [{"GROUP": "A", "NAME": u"りんご", "COUNT": 1},
       {"GROUP": "A", "NAME": u"ゴリラ", "COUNT": 2},
       {"GROUP": "B", "NAME": u"ラッパ", "COUNT": 3}, ]

def func(result, row):
    if not row["GROUP"] in result:
        result[row["GROUP"]] = []

    result[row["GROUP"]].append(row)
    return result

pp(reduce(func, lst, {}))
```

結果:

```
{'A': [{'COUNT': 1, 'GROUP': 'A', 'NAME': 'りんご'},
       {'COUNT': 2, 'GROUP': 'A', 'NAME': 'ゴリラ'}],
 'B': [{'COUNT': 3, 'GROUP': 'B', 'NAME': 'ラッパ'}]}
```

Pythonは複数行の無名関数が書けないので、一度関数(func)を定義しています。
（関数を定義せずとも内包表記で記述できそうですが、可読性は低下すると思います）
関数内での処理の流れは、ご質問のコードと同じです。

また、最初にPythonのバージョン確認と (python 3以上であれば) reduceをimportする処理をしています。これはPython 3.0以上ではreduceが組み込み関数ではなくfunctoolsモジュールに移動しているためです。結果はPython 3.4のものですが、2.7でも上記コードは実行可能です。

Answer (score 1):

reduceじゃないですが、defaultdictを使うといいんじゃないでしょうか。

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from pprint import pprint as pp
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [{ "GROUP": "A", "NAME": u"りんご", "COUNT": 1 },
       { "GROUP": "A", "NAME": u"ゴリラ", "COUNT": 2 },
       { "GROUP": "B", "NAME": u"ラッパ", "COUNT": 3 },]

convert_list = defaultdict(list)
for row in lst:
    convert_list[row["GROUP"]].append(row)

pp(dict(convert_list))
```

結果:

```
{'A': [{'COUNT': 1, 'GROUP': 'A', 'NAME': u'\u308a\u3093\u3054'},
       {'COUNT': 2, 'GROUP': 'A', 'NAME': u'\u30b4\u30ea\u30e9'}],
 'B': [{'COUNT': 3, 'GROUP': 'B', 'NAME': u'\u30e9\u30c3\u30d1'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

[cytoolz](https://github.com/pytoolz/cytoolz/)を使えば：

```
from cytoolz import groupby
lst = [{"GROUP": "A", "NAME": u"りんご", "COUNT": 1},
       {"GROUP": "A", "NAME": u"ゴリラ", "COUNT": 2},
       {"GROUP": "B", "NAME": u"ラッパ", "COUNT": 3}, ]
groupby("GROUP", lst)
```

出力は：

```
{'A': [{'COUNT': 1, 'GROUP': 'A', 'NAME': u'\u308a\u3093\u3054'},
  {'COUNT': 2, 'GROUP': 'A', 'NAME': u'\u30b4\u30ea\u30e9'}],
 'B': [{'COUNT': 3, 'GROUP': 'B', 'NAME': u'\u30e9\u30c3\u30d1'}]}
```